# "The procedure entry point ucrtbase_stdio_common"

Tags: python, windows

I was doing a small project to my friend using python, and I sent him the project(after using cx_Freeze), I sent him all the folders and I checked the program in other PC which doesn't has python and It worked. First the error was that the windows missing file "api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0", So I sent him this file from my PC, but now the error is:

```
"the procedure entry point ucrtbase_stdio_common_vfprintf could not be located in the dynamic link libary api-ms-win-crt-stdio-I1-1-0.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

To run this application you need to install the [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows). Manually copying system libraries is not a solution.

Comment: Here's a newer link for [KB3118401](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118401/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows). Or have the user enable Windows Update, with the option selected to install recommended updates.

Comment: The situation here is that on downlevel systems (prior to Windows 10), a bunch of these "api-ms-win-crt-*" DLLs get installed, which forward their exports to the implementation in ucrtbase.dll. In Windows 10 these DLLs don't exist on disk, but rather, like other API sets, the CRT set is defined virtually in apisetschema.dll.

Comment: @eryksun: Are you sure about Windows 10? The *api-ms-win-\*.dll* files are present in the file system on my Windows 10 machine. They don't appear to contain much code, so I assume they are just forwarders. What's odd, though, is, that they are x86 modules, on a 64-bit system. And they are in %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 (with identical copies in SysWOW64).

Comment: Are they specifically "api-ms-win-**crt**-\*" DLLs? Perhaps they were installed by Visual Studio, though I have it installed without any "api-ms-win-crt-\*" DLLs present, or any "api-\*" DLLs at all. I just have "%SystemRoot%\System32\apisetschema.dll", which defines the API set mapping to implementation DLLs.

Comment: @eryksun: There are also non-CRT DLLs (e.g. api-ms-win-mm-misc-l1-1-1.dll). You are right, though, they might not be core Windows 10 modules. Their timestamps are different from apisetschema.dll (and they seem to coincide roughly with the time I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10 back in 2015). On a system with a clean Windows 10 installation, I didn't find any of them, nor apisetschema.dll, although Visual Studio 12/13/15 are installed on the system.

Comment: ApiSetSchema.dll should be in System32. Make sure you're checking with a 64-bit process; a 32-bit process has System32 redirected to SysWow64, which doesn't have this DLL. ApiSetSchema.dll is only directly used by the OS loader, winload.exe, which passes the kernel the address of the API set mapping, which then gets referenced by the PEB of every NT process. winload.exe also checks `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\ApiSetSchemaExtensions` for extension API sets. By default this key doesn't exist.